# Sorting a linked list with 2 or more nodes

Tags: c

I'm trying to sort a linked list in C, my struct has the field "time", and I want to sort in ascending order by time.

But I cant add new node at the end in case of 2 or more elements, 0 or 1 the code works, for example, when I try this: 7, 6, 2, 9 (these are the "times" of each event), my code sort 2,6,7, but when in '9' my terminal just stop to answering.

Well, thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// My struct
typedef struct event_t 
{
    double time;
    char description[50];
    int id_origin, id_dest;
    struct event_t *prox;
} event_t;

bool event_sort (event_t **list, double time, char description[], int id_origin, int id_dest) 
{
   event_t *newelement = (event_t*)malloc(sizeof(event_t));
   event_t *aux = *list;
   if (newelement!=NULL) {
      newelement->time = time;
      strcpy (newelement->description, description);
      newelement->id_origin = id_origin;
      newelement->id_dest = id_dest;
      // Here I check if the list is empty
      if (*list==NULL) {
         *list = newelement;
         newelement->prox = NULL;
      }
      // Here I check if the list has one element
      else if (aux->prox == NULL) {
         if (aux->time <= time) {
            aux->prox = newelement;
            newelement->prox = NULL;
         }
         else {
            *list = newelement;
            newelement->prox = aux;
         }
      }
      // case if the list have two or more nodes
      else {
         if (aux->time >= time) {
            *list = newelement;
            newelement->prox = aux;
         }
         else {
            while ((aux->prox!=NULL)||(aux->prox->time<=time)) {
               aux = aux->prox;
            }
            newelement->prox = aux->prox;
            aux->prox = newelement;
         }
      }
      return true;
   }
   else {
     return false;
   }
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) 
{

    event_t *list = NULL, aux;
    int number, i;


    printf ("Enter the number of events: ");
    scanf ("%d", &number);
    printf ("\n");
    for (i=0; i<number; i++) 
    {

        printf ("Event %d\n", i+1);

        printf ("Enter the time: ");
        scanf ("%lf", &aux.time);
        printf ("Enter the description: ");
        scanf ("%s", aux.description);
        printf ("Enter the id origin: ");
        scanf ("%d", &aux.id_origin);
        printf ("Enter the id dest: ");
        scanf ("%d", &aux.id_dest);
        printf ("\n");
        event_sort (&list, aux.time, aux.description, aux.id_origin, aux.id_dest);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Showing properly indented code would be a good starting point if you really want us to help.

Comment: Sry, Im not so good with that ;x, I tried improve a bit.

Comment: related: [`O(N log N)` (best & worst) -time, `O(1)`-space inplace Mergesort algorithm for a singly linked linear list](https://gist.github.com/zed/5651186#file-mergesort-linkedlist-py). It is a less general (simpler) version of [`listsort.c`](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/algorithms/listsort.html) that also supports doubly and circularly linked lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the problem is

`while ((aux->prox!=NULL)||(aux->prox->time<=time))`

I guess you meant

`while ((aux->prox!=NULL)&&(aux->prox->time<=time))`

I did not look for other problem.

Bye,

Francis

Comment: yes, that was the problem, but I didnt understand, || seemed right to me ;x Thanks!

Comment: @Kay you are welcome. `||` means "or" and `&&` means "and". Accessing `aux->prox->time` can trigger a segmentation fault if you did not check `(aux->prox!=NULL)` before. So `&&` seemed more logical.

Answer (score 0):

I see a mistake here:

```
else if (aux->prox == NULL)
{
    if (aux->time <= time)
    {
        aux->prox = newelement;
        newelement->prox = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        *list = newelement;
        newelement->prox = aux;
    }
}
```

It should be

```
    else if (aux->prox == NULL)
    {
        if (aux->time <= time)
        {
            aux->prox = newelement;
            newelement->prox = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            newelement->prox = aux;
            *list = newelement;
        }
    }
```

Otherwise you overwrite what `*list` was pointing to before copying it.